# Linear regulator heats up at 60 volts

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, npn

MY goal is  to design a regulator which could receive (12 V to 60 volts DC as an input) and 5 volt with 60 to 70 mA current as an output. The reason I used three BJT's NPN (Q1, Q2, Q3), so I thought I could get decrease the heat dissipation by dividing the current through 3 different BJTs (60 mA/3)= 20 mA. Power dissipation= (Vin At the collector -Emitter)*current= (50.30_5.33)*20/1000= 0.9 W and I test them on bread board and it gets very hot, and it makes sense because 1 watts will almost = to 50 degree Celcius, plus the ambient temperature which makes it 75 degree Celsius.

Any expert there in designing voltage regulator, with a smart solution, or what would you recommend? If I Increase the RX value to 800 ohm, the collector voltage will decrease from 50.5 to 5.33 volts and that is perfect, but the problem is when I change the voltage back to 12 volt, then I won't get 5 volt as an output. If I miss any information[image] to add please let me know, and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

```
[
       --- Operating Point ---

V(n004):     11.0833     voltage
V(a):            6.19012     voltage
V(n002):     50.4175     voltage
V(n003):     6.18692     voltage
V(ve):           05.3231     voltage
V(n005):     5.16179     voltage
V(n001):     60  voltage
V(n006):     5.3231  voltage
Ic(Q2):  0.0319418   device_current
Ib(Q2):  0.000319418     device_current
Ie(Q2):  -0.0322612  device_current
Ic(Q1):  0.0319418   device_current
Ib(Q1):  0.000319418     device_current
Ie(Q1):  -0.0322612  device_current
I(C1):   6.19012e-018    device_current
I(D2):   -0.242137   device_current
I(D1):   -0.00180777     device_current
I(R6):   -0.000638836    device_current
I(R5):   -0.0645224  device_current
I(R3):   -0.0322612  device_current
I(Rx):   -0.0638836  device_current
I(R1):   -0.244583   device_current
I(R4):   -0.0322612  device_current
I(R2):   0.0024466   device_current
I(V2):   -0.308467   device_current
]
```

Comment: This just begs for a DC to DC switcher. Any reason why not? If not, that's fine. But provide some good reasoning about it.

Comment: Exactly what kind of transistors are you using, in what package? What kind of heatsinks?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/ZXTN25100DGTA/ZXTN25100DGCT-ND/1873984

Comment: I am not using a heat sink, but I looked into it, and I did not know how to chose my heat sink. Any recommendation for heat sink ? Thank you very much !!

Comment: @jonk. you mean DC to DC converter? I never looked into that, but I could look into it.

Comment: @user242388 Yes. Your situation just begs for an IC for that purpose. It's a lot of fun doing it discretely, without an IC. But an IC will be lots easier and lots better in the end. And probably not a lot more expensive. I prefer discrete because I'm anachronistic that way and I enjoy tweaking. I'm a hobbyist. But an IC is probably your better bet if you aren't like me.

Comment: @user242388 Besides, ICs have better, more robust protection schemes that are hard to add with discrete parts.

Comment: If you don't want to design your own switcher--which can get tricky for this input voltage range--you might want to buy a module that has the switcher already laid out.

Comment: @jonk@CristobolPolychronopolis thank you very much. What are your thoughts about this regulator, which I am going to post the link? when I looked into their internal device schematic, It is just a very basic design, why theirs can handle the 60 volt  and mine can't ? also the maximum input voltage is 60 volt, do you guys think it will handle 50 volt ? I prefer 60 volt as an input but I guess that is not option for now,  taking cost into consideration.

Comment: @user242388 Where is the 60 V coming from? Do you really want to support something that high?

Comment: I am designing this based on the customer request, because they will be using this on their controllers, and 12 to 60 volt  goes on different controllers,   and yes I really want to support that high voltage if possible. If i increase the RX (resistor value in the above circuit), the voltage Collector decreases as well, and that is what I want but when there is a 12 v input, the output won't be 5 volt, so I can't really increase the RX value in the above resistor. . I am just curious, the way I approach this problem is possible at all?

Comment: With a 5:1 input voltage ratio max/Min exceeding many efficient linear solutions, this looks like an unregulated generator with a wide speed ratio with excess power for a low voltage low power load for 3 simple LEDS.  Try a small battery with a pulse charger regulator or MPPT regulator.

Comment: _"they will be using this on their controllers, and 12 to 60 volt goes on different controllers"_ - what type of controllers, why do they need a single regulator that works on different voltage controllers without any changes, and why is cost so important? Also exactly what is the 5V output powering?

Comment: @user242388 All this stuff is odd. What cost limitations do you have? What about part availability? Does this need to be linear/discrete? (If so, you will have to waste as much as 4 Watts in the supply to deliver 70 mA at 5 V output with 60 V input. Not very efficient. But it's your call. If you feel that's okay, then it's okay.) Can you use *any* switcher ICs? (Switching can be done discretely, it's just more of a pain.) How much ripple on the output can you accept? How "regulated" are the input supplies?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thermal resistance of your transistors, if you only use a small copper area for the tab, is 104°C/W. If you ask them to dissipate 0.9W you should expect that the die temperature will increase by about 90°C above the ambient temperature. With a large copper area (50mm by 50mm of 2oz copper) you can get the thermal resistance down to 42°C/W, but you would still see a temperature increase of about 30°C.

If you want to use this linear regulator you should look for a transistor in a package that is better able to dissipate heat, such as a TO220 package, and look for a compatible heatsink.